# Need advice with jquery image caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transparent, caption

http://www.zurb.com/expo

I've been looking exactly for caption like this for ages. But I'd like to have opacity of that caption's background fe. 50% and then on hover 90% and semi-pulsating text effect. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your browser support, this can be [accomplished using CSS animations (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/LLchY/).

```
h2 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.image:hover h2 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-animation: 2s ease 0s normal none infinite pulse;
    -webkit-animation: 2s ease 0s normal none infinite pulse;
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% { color: #000 }
  50% { color: #FFF }
  100% { color: #000; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% { color: #000 }
  50% { color: #FFF }
  100% { color: #000; }
}
```

If you need older browser support, instead of RGBA, use PNG background-images with alpha transparency, and [jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of CSS animations.